Blender Not Letting Me Render Another Animation
So this is my first time ever using blender at all. I've been trying to make an animation for a project and for some reason, it's not letting me render another bit of animation I did. I'm animation a person walking with a camera showing the person's legs, and then it changes into showing the person thinking. I rendered the first bit (the person walking) as PNGs but isn't able to render the second bit (the person thinking) I do have a deadline so I would appreciate any help. Here are some images:
In the orange is my animation for person walking and in red, it's person thinking.
Tell me if I need to send some photos of specific things.


What do you mean exactly by it doesn't "let you render another animation"?

Without seeing your output settings, your scene, your file etc. this sounds as if you tried to render the same frame range without changing an output name and have Overwrite disabled. This way a second animation would not start if the file names it would try to create already exist in the output folder. But without any information on what you have done this is just a wild guess. (But be careful: if this the reason and you just enable Overwrite again, the image sequence of your first rendered animation will be lost.)

Hi, Person .. I'm afraid the content of your animation is probably not relevant.  We need a look at your settings, in particular, 'Output'.. Without those,  we have nothing to go on. Please edit to show us, in screen-grabs,  everything you can, that might have a bearing on the problem. At best, share a version of your file demonstrating the problem on  https://blend-exchange.com/

@Lauloque I mean that Blender isn't letting me render the second part of my animation, which is person thinking. I don't understand why it isn't letting me render and add the second part of my animation into a rendered animation and a strip for video editing.

Answer:
All I did was add another scene and turned off overwrite. It just suddenly worked again. My advice is to look at the settings over again and try to see if there is a problem there. I also recommend looking at other posts and videos relating to this problem. Also, this is my first time so you should probably just ask your own question and let the professionals try to solve it or try to solve it on your own.

What is the last sentence supposed to mean and who are you talking to?
